# Compilation error: "! Argument of " has an extra }"

Tags: errors, debugging

My TeX document gives me the error:

> (`"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ulasy.fd"`) ! Argument of
>   `"` has an extra `}`. `\par` l.32     `}`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? This is my code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage{reportpage}
\usepackage{epsf,german}
\usepackage{graphics, graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\textwidth 14cm
\theight 22cm
\topmargin 0.0cm
\evensidemargin 1cm
\oddsidemargin 1cm
%\footskip 2cm
\parskip0.5explus0.1exminus0.1ex

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
]
\node[cnode=red,label=0:$\Sigma$] (s) at (6,-3) {};
\node at (0,-4) {$\vdots$};
\node at (3,-4) {$\vdots$};
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
{   \pgfmathparse{\x<4 ? \x : "n"}
    \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$x_{\pgfmathresult}$] (x-\x) at (0,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$\varphi_{\pgfmathresult}$] (p-\x) at (3,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
    \draw (p-\x) -- node[above,sloped,pos=0.3] {$\omega_{\pgfmathresult}$} (s);
}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
{   \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
    {   \draw (x-\x) -- (p-\y);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is that pgfmathparse line suppose to do? And why are you using `"` there?

Comment: What is `\theight`? Did you maybe intend to write `\textheight`?

Comment: Why do you load both `graphics` and `graphicx`? I suggest loading just the latter package. Any why are you loading `epsf` -- that hasn't been necessary for at least five years. The `latexsym` package shouldn't be loaded unless you run LaTeX in "compatibilty mode", i.e., if you wish to emulate the good old days of LaTeX2.09 -- which ended in 1994 [!]. Do yourself a big favor and load the `amssymb` package instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is not good as it seems like a patch of very old documents. It's important to be up-to-date.

1. The package `epsf` is obsolete and should not be used in new documents.
2. The package `german` is obsolete and should not be used in new documents (use `babel`).
3. The package `latexsym` is obsolete and should not be used in new documents (use `amssymb` instead).
4. Loading `graphics` is useless, because you also load `graphicx`.
5. It's unclear why using `\oddsidemargin=1cm`, which leads to a left margin of 3.54cm (use `geometry` for set the pagination parameters).
6. Starting from April 2018, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` can be omitted.
7. With German as the main language, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is necessary.

Edited version, with `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` you need no change to the document body.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[
  textwidth=14cm,
  textheight=22cm,
  hratio=1:1,
  vratio=1:1,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
]
\node[cnode=red,label=0:$\Sigma$] (s) at (6,-3) {};
\node at (0,-4) {$\vdots$};
\node at (3,-4) {$\vdots$};
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
{   \pgfmathparse{\x<4 ? \x : "n"}
    \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$x_{\pgfmathresult}$] (x-\x) at (0,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
    \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$\varphi_{\pgfmathresult}$] (p-\x) at (3,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
    \draw (p-\x) -- node[above,sloped,pos=0.3] {$\omega_{\pgfmathresult}$} (s);
}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
{   \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
    {   \draw (x-\x) -- (p-\y);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]